# Why do some Gulp streams "flow" by default, while others do not?

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe, gulp

Consider these two gulp tasks:

```
gulp.task('src', function(done) {
  gulp.src('docs/*')
    .on('end', function() {
      console.log('ending');
      done();
    });
});

gulp.task('dest', function(done) {
  gulp.src('docs/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('temp'))
    .on('end', function() {
      console.log('ending');
      done();
    });
});
```

Running `gulp dest` behaves as expected, outputting:

```
[12:33:15] Using gulpfile ~/Projects/gulp-exit/gulpfile.js
[12:33:15] Starting 'dest'...
ending
[12:33:15] Finished 'dest' after 13 ms
```

However, running `gulp src` only outputs:

```
[12:31:11] Using gulpfile gulpfile.js
[12:31:11] Starting 'src'...
```

The `'end'` callback is never called. After a bit of debugging, I think the stream in the `dest` task is [**flowing**](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) while the stream in the source task is not.

Signaling the `src` task to flow explicitly by calling `stream.resume()`:

```
gulp.task('src', function(done) {
  gulp.src('docs/*')
    .on('end', function() {
      console.log('ending');
      done();
    })
    .resume();
});
```

Gives the expected output:

```
[12:46:52] Using gulpfile gulpfile.js
[12:46:52] Starting 'src'...
ending
[12:46:52] Finished 'src' after 11 ms
```

I've seen this same mix of behaviors with plugins: [gulp.dest](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpdestpath-options) and [gulp-mocha](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-mocha) seem to return flowing streams while [gulp-logger](https://github.com/chrisgreeff/gulp-logger) and [gulp-gh-pages](https://github.com/rowoot/gulp-gh-pages) do not.

Why the difference in behavior?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why this happens is because some streams have data to be read, and some do not.

`gulp.src('docs/*')` returns a readable stream with data for each file in `docs`. The `end` event only triggers for a readable stream once all the data has been read from the stream.

Normally you would pipe this to another stream which does that automatically, but since you aren't you would need to use:

```
gulp.task('src', function(done) {
  gulp.src('docs/*')
    .on('data', function() {})
    .on('end', function() {
      console.log('ending');
      done();
    });
});
```

Alternatively you can use the `finish` event, which (I think) waits until all data has been pushed into the stream (i.e. it's finished working):

```
gulp.task('src', function(done) {
  gulp.src('docs/*')
    .on('finish', function() {
      console.log('ending');
      done();
    });
});
```

Your second gulp task uses `gulp.dest('temp')` which returns a stream with no data, so `end` is triggered as soon as the stream is done processing.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to why, but I threw together a [stream-end](https://github.com/hurrymaplelad/stream-end) module to smooth out the quirks in the short term:

```
end = require('stream-end')

gulp.task 'logger', (done) ->
  gulp.src 'docs/*'
    .pipe logger()
    .pipe end ->
      console.log('ending')
      done()
```

The callback passed to end is called whether the upstream is flowing or not.